# Retrieving Common rows from two tables having Duplicate records

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, join, sql-server-2008-r2

Its my first question, so don't know where I might go wrong.
Here is my scenario :
I have two tables : tblA and tblB. A procedure that first fills some data in tblA and then the same data in tblB. Now due to certain glitch in procedure query, some values of certain columns were not inserted in tblB but in tblA. I now want to update tblB with the records in tblA. I can't find the corresponding records for update.
For easing the task I have given the sample ready to use query

```
--DROP TABLE #tblA
--DROP TABLE #tblB
--TRUNCATE TABLE #tblA
--TRUNCATE TABLE #tblB
CREATE TABLE #tblA (col1 char(2), col2 char(2), col3 int, col4 char)
CREATE TABLE #tblB (ID char(2),col1 char(2), col2 char(2), col3 int, col4 char)

INSERT INTO #tblA VALUES ('A','B',1,'C')
INSERT INTO #tblA VALUES ('A1','B',2,'C')
INSERT INTO #tblA VALUES ('A1','B',3,'C')

INSERT INTO #tblB VALUES ('I1','A','B',NULL,'C') -- Here we can see that values could not be inserted in col3
INSERT INTO #tblB VALUES ('I2','A1','B',NULL,'C')
INSERT INTO #tblB VALUES ('I3','A1','B',3,'C')
```

What I have tried so far (excluding other queries that I tried, this gives me the closest result)
(i've even tried the commented section)

```
--UPDATE B
--SET B.col3=A.col3
SELECT  DISTINCT A.*, B.*
FROM #tblA A
INNER JOIN #tblB B
ON 1=1
AND A.col1=B.col1
AND A.col2 = B.col2
AND A.col4 = B.col4
--AND (A.col3<>B.col3)
AND (B.col3 IS NULL OR (B.col3 IS NOT NULL AND A.col3=B.col3))
--AND B.col3 IS NULL
```

The result I get is as followed:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    ID  col1    col2    col3    col4
A        B       1       C      I1   A       B      NULL    C
A1       B       2       C      I2   A1      B      NULL    C
A1       B       3       C      I2   A1      B      NULL    C
A1       B       3       C      I3   A1      B      3       C
```

What modification should I do in my select query (which is going to be my update query) so that I get result as followed : (result that removes third row)

```
col1    col2    col3    col4    ID  col1    col2    col3    col4
A        B       1       C      I1   A       B      NULL    C
A1       B       2       C      I2   A1      B      NULL    C  
A1       B       3       C      I3   A1      B      3       C
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, based on the information you have given, I don't think there is a good generalized solution.  I'd need more information about the possible patterns.  As asked, the obvious answer is:

```
SELECT *
FROM #tblA a
inner join #tblb b
on a.col1=b.col1
and a.col2 = b.col2
and a.col4 = b.col4
and a.col3 = right(b.ID,1)
```

alternatively, the last line could be `and a.col3 = coalesce(b.col3,right(b.ID,1))`

Which depends on the ID in #tblb being reflected in Col3.  I don't think that's what you want.  From an algorithmic point of view, if you can't depend on a meaningful ID, I'm not sure there is a good way to do this.  If you can describe the general angorithm you want to apply, then we can write the code to match it.

For example, something that might be meaningful is:

- Tbla joins to tblb on all columns
- When the join fails, I want to pick the first record from tblb that:

  - matches columns 1, 2, and 4 in table a
  - has not already been joined to tbla when sorted by ID

In certain situations I could see that algorithm being useful.  But in essence, your are joining tables with duplicate keys, which gets you a cross join on the records where the key is duplicated.

Hope this helps.  If you clarify a bit more what you are trying to do, I might be able to help a bit more.

UPDATE:

If, as you say in your comment, you simply want to make sure the two tables match exactly, then you can use the following code:

```
CREATE TABLE #tblA (col1 char(2), col2 char(2), col3 int, col4 char)
CREATE TABLE #tblB (col1 char(2), col2 char(2), col3 int, col4 char)

INSERT INTO #tblA VALUES ('A','B',1,'C')
INSERT INTO #tblA VALUES ('A1','B',2,'C')
INSERT INTO #tblA VALUES ('A1','B',3,'C')

INSERT INTO #tblB VALUES ('A','B',NULL,'C') 
INSERT INTO #tblB VALUES ('A1','B',NULL,'C')
INSERT INTO #tblB VALUES ('A1','B',3,'C')

delete from #tblb 
where NOT Exists (Select * from #tbla  a 
    where a.col1 = #tblb.col1
    and a.col2 = #tblb.col2
    and a.col3 = #tblb.col3
    and a.col4 = #tblb.col4)

INSERT #tblb
SELECT * from #tbla
where not exists (select * from #tblb b
    where b.col1 = #tbla.col1
    and b.col2 = #tbla.col2
    and b.col3 = #tbla.col3
    and b.col4 = #tbla.col4)

select * from #tbla a
inner join #tblb b
on b.col1 = a.col1
    and b.col2 = a.col2
    and b.col3 = a.col3
    and b.col4 = a.col4
```

Of course, depending on the size of the table, the size of the row, the indexing of both tables, and how often you run it, it might make more sense to simply drop and reinsert.

It is possible to *only* update the columns that are incorrect, but I think the coding and maintenance overhead would no be worth it, not to mention that performance would probably be pretty bad.

Does this help?

Comment: you are right, ID is not something I am depending on. I added ID column in my example just to determine which row of tblB was begin repeated. All I want is to update tblB with the values that were missed during insert. Truncating tblB and reinserting values in it seems to be only option left for me I guess :(

Comment: I see.  You are just trying to make sure the tables match.  That's pretty easy.  You could simply drop any records from b that don't have an exact match in a and then insert from a any row that doesn't have an exact match in b.  this could be made into an recursive function or stored procedure that runs until the two tables match exactly.  One *important* assumption is that there are no duplicate rows in tbla (that can be handled, but it is more difficult).

Comment: There might be a few but I am not worried about that. Its something I should be able to handle myself. I'll then try to do what is suggested. Delete records with Null Col3 and ReInsert from first table. Thanks for you interest in the question. :)

Answer (score 0):

you don't want to use inner join as there are multiple values comes, you want TOP 1 or Top First record's Col3 value.

So I update the update query as below and this update the result as you want.

```
update  #tblB 
SET col3= 
( select top 1 a.col3 from #tblA a where A.col1=#tblB.col1
AND A.col2 = #tblB.col2
AND A.col4 = #tblB.col4)

select * from #tblB
```

Comment: It doesn't give right answer. it wrongly updates third row as          I3 A1 B  2 C